# VS Code debug port mismatch

Tags: node.js, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code

### Details

In Win10.  VS Code, Help, About...

> [Window Title]
>   Visual Studio Code
>   
>   [Content]
>   Version 1.14.2
>   Commit cb82febafda0c8c199b9201ad274e25d9a76874e
>   Date 2017-07-19T23:34:09.706Z
>   Shell 1.6.6
>   Renderer 56.0.2924.87
>   Node 7.4.0

Generated `launch.json`, adjusted with my `runtime...` settings

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run", "functional-test"
            ],
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Npm script referenced above...

```
"functional-test": "node test/functional/run-foo-tests",
```

### First attempt

I then launch a debug session (F5), which in the Debug Console then yields...

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd --inspect=32825 --debug-brk run functional-test

**Note the additional flags that aren't specified anywhere in my package.json or launch.json.**

In addition to that message above, I am shown a popup in the IDE referencing a connection timeout error...

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED

### Second attempt

If I change the npm script as follows (include `--inspect` flag)...

```
"functional-test": "node --inspect test/functional/run-foo-tests",
```

The Debug Console states...

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd --inspect=17976 --debug-brk run functional-test
>   Debugger listening on port 9229.
>   Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.

Note different port settings. At least the debugger is starting and giving me a port to try and target instead.

**Where is it getting those values?  How can I make them match (without manually editing both launch.json and npm script to assign the same port for both)?**

It never successfully loads and instead I am shown the popup message at the top (mentioned above.)

### Third attempt

If I edit the npm script to add the port...

```
"functional-test": "node --inspect=9229 test/functional/run-foo-tests",
```

And edit launch.json's `port` setting to match...

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run", "functional-test"
        ],
        "port": 9229,
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

I then am rewarded with the following message in the Debug Console...

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd run functional-test
>   Debugger listening on port 5858. 
>   Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
>   {Expected console output...}

It will then work correctly (AFAIK!)  Note that now the Debug Console's second line (echoing/logging the command ran) now matches the `launch.json` `runtimeArgs` settings (where it did not in the first and second attempts.)

**Aside from skull-smashing brute force of trial and error, how was one supposed to figure this out (and surely there must be a better way?)**

### Fourth attempt

Trying to set the port both for the npm script call (obviously not the same as the `node ...` call in the npm script) and the `port` config param and it fails as in the first example.

```
"runtimeArgs": [
    "run", "functional-test", "--inspect=5858"
],
"port": 5858,
```

### Fifth attempt

Of course, as I was writing this, I finally found something like [an answer via google](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools)...

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node --nolazy --debug-brk=5858 myProgram.js"
},
```

Adjusting my script to match yields (in Debug Console)...

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is
>   set.
>  npm.cmd run functional-test 
>  (node:12420)
>   DeprecationWarning: node --debug is deprecated. Please use node
>   --inspect instead.
>  Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858

I am also shown a different popup at the top...

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: Parse Error).

### Sixth attempt

If I change my script to match the info in the Debug Console...

```
"functional-test": "node --nolazy --inspect test/functional/run-foo-tests",
```

Debug Console says...

> Debugging with inspector protocol because a runtime executable is set.
>   npm.cmd run functional-test
>   Debugger listening on port 9229.
>   Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.

And popup is...

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1